# HTTP request timeout while the task is running on the server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a Java EE based web application running on Tomcat and Spring 3.0. My web page sends a request to delete a large set of records. While the request in running in the background I get a timeout error saying: "An internal error occurred".

I think it's a browser timeout issue. Is there a way to fix it? 
In Tomcat's web.xml the session timeout is set to 30.

Do I need to use some Ajax callback instead of post request?

Comment: `a timeout error saying "An internal error occurred"` : that's not coherent. And it's perfectly feasible to have long running answers on tomcat : the browser waits for much more than 30s if there is no cut.

Comment: Its not definitely browser issue for sure, if it saying _internal_ it mean by _server_ fault, and please do edit your question headline.

Comment: Maybe you could use a new thread to delete those records? The main thread would then redirect the user to a page with a kind of "records deletion started" message.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Apache HTTP web server in the front of Tomcat?

There are several layers of timeouts:

1. At the apache web server level (See the Timeout setting for mod_proxy, see the worker.properties file for mod_jk)
2. At the tomcat connector level (See the tomcat conf/server.xml for socket timeouts).
3. At the web application session expiration level (See the tomcat webapps/WEB-INF/web.xml session timeout settings
4. Database timeout - whist making a long database query, the database query timeout occurred and spit you back out.

Here's what to do:

1. Make sure you have the correct units for the timeout. Some things
   use seconds, some minutes, some milliseconds. Make sure you have the
   right one.
2. Use tcpdump and your java debugger connected to Tomcat
   to see where the timeout is occurring. Tcpdump is useful because you
   can view the network traffic that is going on up until your timeout
   happens. Java debugger is helpful because you will want to look at
   exactly what is happening on the request on the server level.

From these, you can find the ultimate source of the timeout and update this ticket with that information.